# How to print <?xml version="1.0"?> using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Is there any way to have an XDocument print the xml version when using the ToString method? Have it output something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ELMResponse [
]>
<Response>
<Error> ...
```

I have the following:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(new XDocumentType("Response", null, null, "\n"), ...
```

which will print this which is fine, but it is missing the "<?xml version" as stated above.

```
<!DOCTYPE ELMResponse [
]>
<Response>
<Error> ...
```

I know that you can do this by outputting it manually my self. Just wanted to know if it was possible by using XDocument.

Comment: Side note: the fact that XDocument.ToString() omits the XDeclaration also means you won't see the declaration in the VS debugger watch window, even though the XDeclaration is in the XDocument.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

By using XDeclaration. This will add the declaration.

But with `ToString()` you will not get the desired output.

You need to use `XDocument.Save()` with one of his methods.

Full sample:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "yes"), 
        new XElement("blah", "blih"));

var wr = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(wr);
Console.Write(wr.ToString());
```

Comment: Yep you're right, I missed the part when he said he was using ToString(). So, use XDeclaration AND Save() (to file or a memorystream).

Comment: or to a string via stringwriter ;-)

Comment: Similar comment to above, as the question indicated a DTD, standalone must be "no".

Comment: simply wr.toString() works, no need to to have GetStringBuilder() in between

Comment: Tip: You could create an extension method to add the functionality to the `ToString` method. E.g. `public static string ToString(this XDocument doc, bool addDeclaration)`

Comment: It seems that the XDeclaration does not allow for utf-8 encoding, how can this be? It seems to have effect, since null in standalone actually creates a response without the standalone attribute.

Comment: Odd behavior of ToString, in my opinion. I would have expected it to behave as Save does.

Comment: This answer only works for utf-16, because it use StringWriter will encode the stream as utf-16. Its ToString() method consistently modifies the declaration. For utf-8, you can use the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4337505/456456 by @Kevin.

Comment: The values you specify under `new XDeclaration(…)` above are not always respected with this method (which is what @R.Schreurs also hints at). I just wrote a ___long___ answer about this where I also propose an extension method of the kind suggested by Bart Friederichs in his comment above.

Comment: Two important things. 1. `document.ToString()` will strip the declaration. 2. `document.Declaration.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + document.ToString()` will show the declaration if sitemap.xml is displayed via the Chrome Inspector/Network, but not via direct URL in Chrome (strips the declaration from view).

Answer (score 15):

This is by far the best way and most managable:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", new XElement("Child", "台北 Táiběi.")));

string mystring;

using(var sw = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(var strw = new StreamWriter(sw, System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8))
    {
         xdoc.Save(strw);
         mystring = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sw.ToArray());
    }
}
```

and i say that just because you can change encoding to anything by changing .UTF8 to .Unicode or .UTF32

Answer (score 14):

Late answer to an old question, but I shall try to provide more details than the other answers.

The thing you ask about, is called an *XML declaration*.

First of all, the `XDocument` has a property [`Declaration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration) of type [`XDeclaration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdeclaration) for this. You can either user another overload of the `XDocument` constructor:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
  new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null), // <--- here
  new XDocumentType("Response", null, null, "\n"), ... 
  );
```

or set the property later:

```
xdoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
```

But depending on how you *save* or *write* your `XDocument` later, the declaration (or parts of it) may be ignored. More on that later.

The XML declaration can have a number of appearances. Here are some valid examples:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                        new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null)
<?xml version="1.1"?>                                        new XDeclaration("1.1", null, null)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>                    new XDeclaration("1.0", "us-ascii", null)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                       new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>                      new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", null)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>       new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no")
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>      new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes")
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>                       new XDeclaration("1.0", null, "yes")
```

Note that `XDeclaration` will happily accept invalid arguments, so it is up to you to get it right.

In many cases the first one, `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, the form you ask for, is perfect (it is not needed to give `encoding` if it is just UTF-8 (including ASCII), and it is not needed to specify `standalone` if its intended value is `"no"` or if there are no DTDs).

Note that `xdoc.ToString()` goes do the override from the `XNode` base class (in my version of .NET) *and does not include the XML declaration*. You can easily enough create a method to deal with that, like this:

```
public static string ToStringWithDecl(this XDocument d)
  => $"{d.Declaration}{Environment.NewLine}{d}";
```

Some of the other answers indicate that the `XDeclaration` will be respected if you use `xdoc.Save` or `xdoc.WriteTo` methods, but that is not quite true:

- They might include an XML declaration even if you have none in your `XDocument`
- They might specify the encoding used by the target file, stream, writer, string builder etc. instead of the encoding you gave, or instead of omitting the encoding if you did that in your `XDeclaration`
- They might change your version from e.g. `1.1` into `1.0`

Of course, when you save/write to a file, it is a good thing that the declaration matches the true encoding of that file!

But sometimes when you write to a string in mememory, you do not want the `utf-16` (even if you realize that .NET strings are in UTF-16 internally). You can use the extension method above instead. Or you can use the following hacked version of the method from EricSch's answer:

```
  string xdocString;
  using (var hackedWriter = new SuppressEncodingStringWriter())
  {
    xdoc.Save(hackedWriter);
    xdocString = hackedWriter.ToString();
  }
```

where you have:

```
// a string writer which claims its encoding is null in order to omit encoding in XML declarations
class SuppressEncodingStringWriter : StringWriter
{
  public sealed override Encoding Encoding => null;
}
```

---

Addition. Whoever updated the type `StringWriter` (and its base type `TextWriter`) to use *nuallable reference types*, decided that properties such as [`Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.encoding) and [`FormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.formatprovider) should *not* be nullable. Maybe that was unfortunate? Anyway, if you have nullable reference types turned on, you may need to write `null!` instead of just `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Just type this

```
var doc =
    new XDocument (
        new XDeclaration ("1.0", "utf-16", "no"),
        new XElement ("blah", "blih")
    );
```

And you get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<blah>blih</blah>
```

Comment: In addition, as the question indicates the use of a DTD, standalone must be "no".

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET Solution CODE

**Code**

```
   Dim _root As XElement = <root></root>
   Dim _element1 As XElement = <element1>i am element one</element1>
   Dim _element2 As XElement = <element2>i am element one</element2>
   _root.Add(_element1)
   _root.Add(_element2)
   Dim _document As New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"), _root)
   _document.Save("c:\xmlfolder\root.xml")
```

**Output** Note(please open output in notepad )

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <root>
   <element1>i am element one</element1>
   <element2>i am element one</element2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is:

```
var fullXml = $"{xDocument.Declaration}{xDocument}";
```

If your **xDocument.Declaration** is empty, just add it.