# Force XDocument to write to String with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, linq-to-xml

I want to be able to write XML to a String with the declaration and with UTF-8 encoding.  This seems mighty tricky to accomplish.

I have read around a bit and tried some of the popular answers for this but the they all have issues.  My current code correctly outputs as UTF-8 but does not maintain the original formatting of the XDocument (i.e. indents / whitespace)!

Can anyone offer some advice please?

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), xelementXML);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (XmlWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    xml.Save(xw);
    xw.Flush();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    String xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The XML requires the formatting to be identical to the way `.ToString()` would format it i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <node>blah</node>
</root>
```

What I'm currently seeing is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><root><node>blah</node></root>
```

**Update**
I have managed to get this to work by adding `XmlTextWriter` settings... It seems VERY clunky though!

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
settings.Indent = true;
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlTextWriter.Create(ms, settings))
{
    xml.Save(xw);
    xw.Flush();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    String blah = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: What 'formatting'? You haven't said anything about formatting!

Comment: The usual whitespace / formatting that you get if you just to a `.ToString()` on an `XDocument` or `XElement`

Comment: Please give a sample input document so we can test answers.

Comment: @John - Done... It is just the whitespace formatting I am bothered about as I later hash the XML so need to be 100% sure the output is consistent.

Comment: I've provided a rather simpler way of doing it.

Comment: Title and approved answer suggest this is about UTF-8 versus UTF-16, but his own solution shows it is about formatting / pretty-printing instead. Instead of the settings, he could simply do `xw.Formatting=Formatting.Indented` .

Comment: A related thread is [How to print `<?xml version=“1.0”?>` using `XDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957124/).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml",
                                       LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
        doc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
        StringWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter();
        doc.Save(writer, SaveOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine(writer);
    }

    private class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
    }
}
```

Of course, you haven't shown us how you're building the document, which makes it hard to test... I've just tried with a hand-constructed `XDocument` and that contains the relevant whitespace too.

Comment: Works a treat, thanks - is there no way to get the encoding sorted without inheriting from StringWriter?

Comment: @Chris: It's *possible* that there is some way of getting the TextWriter overload to ignore the encoding that the TextWriter advertises, but I've found this to be a really simple hack to get the job done. (You only need it in one place...)

Comment: Yeah I like it - it's FAR better than the method I came up with. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try XmlWriterSettings:

```
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
xws.Indent = true;
```

And pass it on like

```
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws))
```

Answer (score 0):

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3288376/1430535

```
return xdoc.Declaration.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + xdoc.ToString();
```