# Modifying element of Json string (in C#)

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to modify an attribute of an XML string using Json in C#. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
XmlDocument serializedFormXml = new XmlDocument();
serializedFormXml.LoadXml(mySerializedForm);

string formJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(serializedFormXml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
JObject formJsonObj = JObject.Parse(formJsonString);
formJsonObj["@code"] = "myNewValue";
var xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(formJsonObj.ToString()).ToString();
```

When I do this I get get an exception on the last line:
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlDocumentWrapper' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IXmlElement'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix modify my form attribute "code"?

This is the XML I'm using:

```
<Form code="XYZ">
   <Info>Data</Info>
   .....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's going to be way, way easier with [Linq-to-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387052.aspx):

```
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(mySerializedForm);
        doc.Root.SetAttributeValue(doc.Root.Name.Namespace + "code", "myNewValue");
        var xml = doc.ToString();
```

This drops the XML declaration.   If you need the XML declaration included, you can use the following extension method:

```
public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    public static string ToXml(this XDocument xDoc)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            xDoc.Save(writer);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And then write:

```
        var xml = doc.ToXml();
```

If specifically you need to make the encoding string say "UTF-8", use `Utf8StringWriter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871738/force-xdocument-to-write-to-string-with-utf-8-encoding/3871822#3871822).

**Update**

The reason you code fails is that you stripped the XML root element name away when you converted to json by passing `true` here:

```
        string formJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(serializedFormXml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
```

Thus you need to add it back when converting back:

```
        var xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(formJsonObj.ToString(), serializedFormXml.DocumentElement.Name).ToString();
```

Comment: You are exactly right, that was the problem. Thanks for spotting that I was stripping the root element, all is working now and happy times have returned :)