# How to make sure a XDocument is saved with utf-8 file encoding?

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am creating a Xml file with the following code (the byte array returned by `Serialize()` is written to a `FileStream` later):

```
    public byte[] Serialize()
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteXmlToStream(stream);

            stream.Position = 0;                

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string resultString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultString);
            }
        }
    }

    private void WriteXmlToStream(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        var document = 
            new XDocument(
                new XElement("Coleta",
                    new XElement("Operador", Operador),
                    new XElement("Sujeito", Sujeito),
                    new XElement("Início", DataHora.ToString(Constantes.FormatoDataHora)),
                    new XElement("Descrição", Descrição),
                    // and so on
                    )
                )
            );

        document.Save(stream);
    }
```

But when I open the saved file, the unicode characters are "wrong":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Coleta>
      <Operador>Nome do Operador do Sofware</Operador>
      <Sujeito>Nome Paciente de Teste</Sujeito>
      <InÃ­cio>2015-05-19T02:24:10.10Z</InÃ­cio>
      <DescriÃ§Ã£o>Coleta de teste para validaÃ§Ã£o do formato de arquivo.</DescriÃ§Ã£o>
      <Sensores>
        <SensorInfo>
          <Sensor>
            <Nome />
            <PosiÃ§Ã£oAnatÃ´mica>NÃ£oEspecificada</PosiÃ§Ã£oAnatÃ´mica>
            <Canais>
              <Canal>
              <!-- and so on -->
```

<strike>So what am I not doing, or doing wrong, and how should I fix it? I always have a hard time understanding these encoding peculiarities.</strike>

As mentioned in the comments, it happens because file editors are not opening the generated file with the correct (utf-8) encoding.

So my question is: how should I force encoding to the file?

UPDATE: it seems like this answer might be relevant:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871822/401828

Comment: How are you opening the file? It's probably just Notepad being rubbish... make sure you open it in UTF-8.

Comment: I've tried this and it works fine, so I can only re-iterate what Jon Skeet says above - how are you verifying the output?

Comment: re the `new StreamReader()` etc - any reason you can't just use `return stream.ToArray();` ?

Comment: @JonSkeet Well your tips worked: I opened it in Sublime Text,  then clicked "File->Reopen with encoding-> utf-8, and problem is fixed. Now the question is: how can I create the file so that Text Editors know automatically it's encoded as utf-8?

Comment: @MarcGravell it has to do with the `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultString);` part, but this is legacy already, since I was not using XDocument before. Gonna try your suggested change, thanks.

Comment: @heltonbiker frankly, that's the wrong way (and too late) to try and apply encoding; if you want a specific encoding, it would be better to use a TextWriter when writing the data; however, I strongly suspect it defaults to UTF-8 *anyway*, so it shouldn't need anything

Comment: I've looked it up, and the encoding is picked out from the `.Declaration`

Comment: @MarcGravell I tried your simplification, but now it saves a lengh-encoded string (with three bytes before the actual string), and that's not what I need. As I said, this is something (encodings, etc.) I have not yet got familiar with, so I appreciate any suggestion. The structure of the code in my program only requires me that the `Serialize()` method returns a byte array representing a XML string encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: @heltonbiker I very much doubt that is length encoding; more likely: that's a BOM (the sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF). Do you have a strong objection to a BOM? But give me a sec,  I'll see what I can find

Comment: BTW: you should *not* attempt to format dates manually for xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want fine-grained encoding control, you probably want to control the `TextWriter`; for example, in the example below I'm using UTF-8 *sans-BOM*. However, if possible, you could also write directly to a file via a `FileStream`...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var bytes = new Program().Serialize();
        File.WriteAllBytes("my.xml", bytes);
    }
    public byte[] Serialize()
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteXmlToStream(stream);

            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private void WriteXmlToStream(Stream stream)
    {
        var document =
            new XDocument(
                new XElement("Coleta",
                    new XElement("Operador", "foo"),
                    new XElement("Sujeito", "bar"),
                    new XElement("Início", DateTime.Now),
                    new XElement("Descrição", "Descrição")
                    // and so on
                    )
                );
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            document.Save(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

The above works fine, and encodes correctly.

To write directly to a file instead:

```
public void Serialize(string path)
{
    using (var stream = File.Create(path))
    {
        WriteXmlToStream(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: @heltonbiker side note, and to repeat: please don't format the `DateTime`s yourself: let the xml api worry about the correct format for dates.