# ASP.Net return XML document from XNode with proper encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, utf-8, utf-16

I want to return an XML document represented as an XNode from asp.net

I have

```cs
public ContentResult SaveXml(XDocument doc, int statusCode){
    StringBuilder b = new();
    using var writer = new StringWriter(b);
    doc.Save(writer);

    return new ContentResult { Content = builder.ToString(), ContentType="text/xml", StatusCode = statusCode }
}
```

This returns an XML string that is UTF-8 encoded, but it has the tag `<?xml encoding="utf-16" ?>`, which makes my API consumers very confused and angry.

I think this happens because C# strings are utf16 so when the doc saves it sees its saving to a utf16 string and thinks "I must be saving to a UTF 16 string and will set my header accordingly"

The workaround I found was to change `Content = builder.ToString()` to `Content = builder.ToString().Replace("utf-16","utf-8")` but that's an extremely ugly hack.

Am I correct about the cause of this issue? If so how do I resolve this?

Comment: (Your use case is somewhat different from the duplicate, but the root cause and *answer* are the same.)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3871738/1997232).

Comment: "which makes my API consumers very confused and angry" why?