# XDocument.Load losing Declaration

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a XML template file like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<AutomatedDispenseResponse>
    <header shipmentNumber=""></header>
    <items></items>
</AutomatedDispenseResponse>
```

When I use XDocument.Load, for some reason the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
```

is dropped.

How do I load the file into a XDocument and not losing the declaration at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's not *really* dropping the declaration on load - it's when you're writing the document out that you're missing it. Here's a sample app which works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.Declaration);
    }
}
```

And test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" ?>
<Foo>
  <Bar />
</Foo>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
```

The declaration *isn't* shown by `XDocument.ToString()`, and may be replaced when you use `XDocument.Save` because you may be using something like a `TextWriter` which already knows which encoding it's using. If you save to a stream or just to a filename, it's preserved in my experience.

Comment: I figured that out shortly after posting (of course). The intellisense was throwing me off since it was calling ToString(). I just need to do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957124/how-to-print-xml-version1-0-using-xdocument/957161#957161

Answer (score 2):

It is loaded. You can see it and access parts of it using:

```
XDocument.Parse(myDocument).Declaration
```